# How to check if notification has been viewed like in facebook?

Tags: django, facebook, notifications

Whenever there are facebook notifications a red indicator appears until the notifications have been viewed for the first time.

How could I implement something similar on my site (preferably with django if anything needs to be done server-side)?

Comment: Well you can have `is_read` attr in your notifications model. Which you should set to `True` once the notification is read. P.S there are plenty of good notifications app out there check [django-notification](https://github.com/pinax/django-notification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be:
Have a field in the models for `viewed_at` which is nullable. Once viewed, set the date. If no value is set, that means the user has not viewed it yet.

If there are multiple users whom this feature needs to be extended to, have a foreign key reference:

```
class MyViewableObject(models.Model):
    #fields

class MyViewableViewedBy(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    viewable = models.ForeignKey(MyViewableObject)
```

Now, when `MyViewableObject` is viewed, in the view method, create an association for the `request.user` in the `MyViewableViewedBy` model.

The user has not viewed if there is no corresponding user entry for the object in the model `MyViewableViewedBy`